# Pandas: Find row wise frequent value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with binary values. I want to find out frequent value in each row. This dataset have couple of millions records. What would be the most efficient way to do it? Following is the sample of the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('myData.csv', sep = ',')
data.head()
bit1    bit2    bit2    bit4    bit5    frequent    freq_count
0       0       0       1       1       0           3
1       1       1       0       0       1           3
1       0       1       1       1       1           4
```

I want to create `frequent` as well as `freq_count` columns like the sample above. These are not part of original dataset and will be created after looking at all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def freq_stat(df):
    a = df.values
    zero_c = (a==0).sum(1)
    one_c = a.shape[1] - zero_c
    df['frequent'] = (zero_c<=one_c).astype(int)
    df['freq_count'] = np.maximum(zero_c, one_c)
    return df
```

Sample run -

```
In [305]: df
Out[305]: 
   bit1  bit2  bit2.1  bit4  bit5
0     0     0       0     1     1
1     1     1       1     0     0
2     1     0       1     1     1

In [308]: freq_stat(df)
Out[308]: 
   bit1  bit2  bit2.1  bit4  bit5  frequent  freq_count
0     0     0       0     1     1         0           3
1     1     1       1     0     0         1           3
2     1     0       1     1     1         1           4
```

### Benchmarking

Let's test out this one against the fastest approach from [`@jezrael's soln`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538262/3293881) :

```
from scipy import stats

def mod(df): # @jezrael's best soln 
    a = df.values.T
    b = stats.mode(a)

    df['a'] = b[0][0]
    df['b'] = b[1][0]
    return df
```

Also, let's use the same setup from the other post and get the timings -

```
In [323]: np.random.seed(100)
     ...: N = 10000
     ...: #[10000 rows x 20 columns]
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(N,20)))
     ...: 

# @jezrael's soln 
In [324]: %timeit mod(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.92 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [325]: %timeit freq_stat(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 496 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html#scipy.stats.mode):

```
from scipy import stats

a = df.values.T
b = stats.mode(a)
print(b)
ModeResult(mode=array([[0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64), count=array([[3, 3, 4]]))

df['frequent'] = b[0][0]
df['freq_count'] = b[1][0]
print (df)
   bit1  bit2  bit2.1  bit4  bit5  frequent  freq_count
0     0     0       0     1     1         0           3
1     1     1       1     0     0         1           3
2     1     0       1     1     1         1           4
```

Use [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

def f(x):
    a, b = Counter(x).most_common(1)[0]
    return pd.Series([a, b])

df[['frequent','freq_count']] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Another solution:

```
def f(x):
    counts = np.bincount(x)
    a = np.argmax(counts)
    b = np.max(counts)
    return pd.Series([a,b])

df[['frequent','freq_count']] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Alternative:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in x:
        d[i] += 1
    return pd.Series(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0])


df[['frequent','freq_count']] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 10000
#[10000 rows x 20 columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(N,20)))

In [140]: %timeit df.apply(f1, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.78 s per loop

In [141]: %timeit df.apply(f2, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop

In [142]: %timeit df.apply(f3, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.7 s per loop

In [143]: %timeit mod(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.37 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit mod1(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.88 ms per loop
```

---

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from scipy import stats

def f1(x):
    a, b = Counter(x).most_common(1)[0]
    return pd.Series([a, b])

def f2(x):
    counts = np.bincount(x)
    a = np.argmax(counts)
    b = np.max(counts)
    return pd.Series([a,b])

def f3(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in x:
        d[i] += 1
    return pd.Series(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0])

def mod(df):
    a = df.values.T
    b = stats.mode(a)

    df['a'] = b[0][0]
    df['b'] = b[1][0]
    return df

def mod1(df):
    a = df.values
    b = stats.mode(a, axis=1)

    df['a'] = b[0][:, 0]
    df['b'] = b[1][:, 0]
    return df
```